# Dynamically change logging formatter in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am using python logging, at one point of program I need a logging format like this,

```
"[%(asctime)s] [%(service_id)s] [%(
    levelname)s] [%(hostname)s] [%(host_ip)s] [%(client_agent)s] [%(client_ip)s] [%(filename)20s:%(lineno)d]"
```

at another point I need a format like this and so on,

```
 "[%(asctime)s] [%(service_id)s] [%(
    levelname)s] [%(hostname)s] [%(host_ip)s]"
```

My logging format should dynamically change through out the program. How to achieve this?

Comment: You could just call `handler.setFormatter(...)` everytime you need a new format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change the format by calling:

```
logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s %(service_id)s %(
levelname)s %(hostname)s %(host_ip)s %(message)s")
```

or

```
logging.basicConfig(
  format="%(asctime)s {} %(message)s".format(get_your_hostname_somewhere())
)
```

the above as pointed by blues comment, would work on the initial setup only.

I believe to get `hostname`(and all the other fancy data) in there like that you will need to implement a `logging.Filter` or format it into your logged message if they are defined in the context you call your logger.

After a second review I came across [this HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging) which might be helpful as well, a given example would be something along the lines of:

```py
import logging

# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create console handler and set level to debug
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(service_id)s %(
levelname)s %(hostname)s %(host_ip)s %(message)s')

# add formatter to ch
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

# add ch to logger
logger.addHandler(ch)

logger.info("message")
```

and on the other file get the logger and define a handler once more, but define the Formatter with the new format.

Comment: This doesn't work. `basicConfig` can only be used to setup logging *once*. Calling it again will not change the format (or anything else)

Comment: @blues indeed, thank you for mentioning it. edited response to try and make it more clear, also found more documentation that might provide helpful for this case!